# How to Play An Audio On Page Load Using Html?

Tags: html, audio, onload

I tried playing an audio when the webpage loads, I used The Following Html Code For It.

```
<audio src="Pvs.mp3" id="my_audio" loop="loop"></audio>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
      document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
    }
  </script>
  </audio>
```

I used The Above Code Inside the body tag
But it's Not Working..
Is There Any Other Workibg Way To Play an Audio File On Page Load?

Comment: You have two ending `</audio>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just before `</body>` ending tag

```
<script>  
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
});  
</script>
```